# Mongodb group by field using $substr

Tags: mongodb

I have an query to group by file name. Something like

```
db.images.aggregate([ <query> ,        

             { $group: { _id: { $substr: [ "$FileName", 3, -1 ] }, files: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },

             { $sort: { UploadDate : -1 } }
        ])
```

I need to set start index in substring function to first match symbol "_".
Something like `"$FileName.indexOf('_')"`. Could anyone help me?

Comment: There's no operator to do this in the aggregation framework at present; the related issue is [SERVER-8951](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8951). I would suggest, at insert, computing the substring before the first instance of "_" and storing it on the document, as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, I did the same as workaround

Answer (score 0):

There is a dirty but working solution based on this link http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/ugly-way-to-parse-a-string-with-aggregation-framework So, why not?

To find a symbol position in the string, we can build a complex condition to sequentally check each symbol of the string for matching symbol. It is basically similar to how indexOf function works.

```
function indexOf(field, character) {
    var array = [];
    var maxPos = 50;
    var searchStart = 0;

    array[maxPos]={"$cond":{"if":{"$eq":[{"$substr":[field,maxPos,1]},character]},"then":maxPos+1,else:0}};

    for ( var i=maxPos-1; i>searchStart-1; i-- ) {
         array[i]={"$cond":{"if":{"$eq":[{"$substr":[field,i,1]},character]},"then":i,"else":array[i+1]}}
    }

    return array[searchStart];
}
```

So, your MongoDB request will look like this:

```
db.images.aggregate([ <query> ,
             { $group: { _id: { $substr: ["$FileName", indexOf("$FileName", "_"), 999] }, files: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
             { $sort: { UploadDate : -1 } }
        ])
```