# Get distinct first words in a string

Tags: mongodb, distinct

I try to get distinct first words in a field in a database:

```
db.mycollection.distinct(substr(0, city.indexOf(' ')),{"state":"FirstState"})
```

But that does not work obviosly, but maybe it helps to get an idea about what I want to do.

Say I have two documents:

```
{
  "_id": "10280",
  "city": "FirstCity is great",
  "state": "FirstState",
  "pop": 2224
},
{
  "_id": "10282",
  "city": "SecondCity even greater",
  "state": "FirstState",
  "pop": 5574
}
```

I then want to get:

```
["FirstCity","SecondCity"]
```

I.e. get distinct values of `city` field's `first word` in array.
Is there any way to do that?

Best Regards

Comment: Your question is unclear. Perhaps we will understand if you can show us sample document with the expected output

Comment: @Styvane Please see updated question.

Comment: It seems like you cannot achieve it until mongo 3.3.6. But current stable release is 3.2.10. Look this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282334/mongodb-group-by-field-using-substr)

Comment: @gzc documents are already in database, maybe someone knows some other way to do that besides aggregate?

Comment: do you have to do this from the cmd- and all in one query?

Comment: @deeveeABC Well it would be great, but all solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method to return the list as follows

**Mongo Shell:**

```
cities = db.mycollection.distinct("city", {"state" : "FirstState"}).map(function(city){
   return city.split(" ")[0]; 
});
printjson(cities);
```

**Sample Output**

```
[ "FirstCity", "SecondCity" ]
```

Comment: Good solution tnx!

Comment: You maybe have an idea about how to also get only unique elements in array?